# Erlang lists:foreach side effects

Tags: erlang

Can the **lists:foreach** function be used to delete an element in the callback function? i.e. Will there be any problem if modifying the list on which the iteration is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess that the simple answer for this is no.

[`lists:foreach/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#foreach-2) function is used to run a specific function on all the elements in the list. In addition to this, it returns the `ok` atom. It does not returns a list, as the documentation defines.

> `foreach(Fun, List) -> ok`
>   Calls `Fun(Elem)` for each element `Elem` in `List`. This function is used for its side effects and the evaluation order is defined to be the same as the order of the elements in the list.

If you want to perform some function on every element and return a list with the results from this function you can use [`lists:map/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#map-2).  Although, note that in contrast to `foreach`, `map` does not guarantee any evaluation order.

If you just want to delete an element from the list just use [`lists:delete/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#delete-2).

Comment: Thanks. I forgot that variables are immutable in erlang. Still what does **side effects** mean in the documentation. Whose side effects the documentation is referring ?

Comment: I guess that the side effects means that it does not return anything, it just used to run something for every element in the list without caring about its return value. For example if you want to send some process `Pid` all the elements of `List` you can do `lists:foreach(fun(E)->Pid ! E end, List)`.

Comment: Note that the specific property that makes `foreach` suitable for functions that have side effects is that it is guaranteed to apply the function to the elements of the list following the list order. Even though you could as well use `map` and ignore the result, in theory map doesn't guarantee any evaluation order (since evaluation order is irrelevant for pure functions)

Comment: Thanks @SamuelRivas , that's absolutely right and I've added this note to my answer.